# Removing part of the string

Tags: sql, text, trim

SQL....On my table I have attribute table with “Pat0700-1700” on my report I want to drop the Pat and only display 0700-1700. How would I accomplish this on SQL. I have search and tried the substring with neg results.

Comment: Please also tag with your specific _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.), as the exact answer you seek might depend on the version.

Comment: please post here what you have tried. it helps to better understand the problem!

Comment: May be try `REPLACESTR()` like finction.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

On these following RDBMS:

- Oracle
- MySQL
- DB2
- StandardSQL

you can try with the function SUBSTR():

```
SELECT SUBSTR(<column>, 4) AS substr_string 
FROM <table>
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
substr_string
-------------
0700-1700
```

Comment: In _standard_ ANSI/ISO SQL it would be `SUBSTRING(<column> FROM 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

The standard SQL method would be `replace()`:

```
select replace(col, 'Pat', '')
```

Given that the rest of the string has a fixed format -- 9 characters -- you might also find that one of these is appropriate (and more general):

```
select right(col, 9)
select substr(col, 4, 9)     -- or perhaps substring()
```